# SQL Case Query Optimization

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, case

I have a subquery that I am using in a much larger select query that I need to optimize in order to upload it to Domo.  I am trying to add a Yes/No column for whether or not a transaction includes a specific item.  This is to be displayed on all lines of the transaction.

It works properly, but I'm working with so much data that the software times out before it can get through all of it.  I can run the query with no problems in SQL SMS 2012, but is there a simpler/faster way to do this?  Thank you!

```
case 
when transactions.transaction_id in 
    (select transaction_id
    from transaction_lines
    where item_id_0 = 'msa500'
    group by transaction_id) then 'Yes'
else 'No'
end as ContainsMSA500
```

Comment: you can move your subquery to a CTE. Should work faster, as the CTE will be retrieved once, while the sub-query is retrieved for each row

Comment: Thank you...I will do some research into CTEs.  Could you give me an example?  I am very new to SQL.

Comment: @cha . . . Where do you get that idea?  SQL Server does not materialize CTEs in general as far as I know.  If you know of documentation that says otherwise, I would be very happy to see it.

Comment: @cha Sorry, have to agree with Gordon - that is not how a CTE works, at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you nailed it. I have to agree with you that CTE's are not materialised. In this case, I think CROSS APPLY should work faster. This article does some performance analysis http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize this by doing:

```
(case when exists (select 1
                   from transaction_lines tl
                   where tl.item_id_0 = 'msa500' and
                         tl.transaction_id = transactions.transaction_id
                  )
      then 'Yes'
      else 'No'
 end) as ContainsMSA500
```

Then create an index on `transaction_lines(transaction_id, item_id_0)`.

The problem with formulating this as a `group by` is that SQL Server has to generate the whole list every time.  By formulating it using `exists`, SQL Server can look up the value in an index -- much, much faster in general.

In SQL Server 2012, the `in` version might be optimized:

(case when transaction_id in (select  tl.transaction_id
                                 from transaction_lines tl
                                 where tl.item_id_0 = 'msa500' 
                                )
          then 'Yes'
          else 'No'
     end) as ContainsMSA500

ALthough logically the same, removing the `group by` might help.

The final option would be to put this in the `from` clause of the query.  That is hard to explain without seeing the whole query.

Comment: Thank you!  That looks much better!